# Reduce Fortran function call overhead

Tags: performance, function, optimization, fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran code like this:

file1.f90

```
program myprog
 use func1mod
    do i=1,N
       call subroutine1
    enddo
    subroutine subroutine1
         integer*8::var1,var2,var3,...
         do j=1,N
            x=func1(var1,var2,var3,..)
            computations based on x
         enddo
    return
    end
end
```

file2.f90

```
 module func1mod
 contains
     func1(var1,var2,var3,....)
         func1=some computations based on var1, var2, var3, ...
      return
     end function func1
 end module func1mod
```

function `func1` does not modify any of its arguments. It computes a value based on the arguments and returns a value. The # of arguments is large but the function is less than 30 lines of code. What is the best approach to reduce the function call overhead.
One approach would be to inline the function. Is there any other way out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best you can do is be as explicit as possible about the semantics of the function, turn optimization up as high as possible, and let the compiler make the best decision it can about how best to implement the call.   Make sure the dummy variables are marked `intent(in)`, and mark the function as `pure` -  although if it's only 30 lines, the compiler will doubtless notice these things anyway at high optimization - and check your compiler options to see if there's anything you can do to encourage (for instance) inlining.

Comment: For this case all the arguments are read only, so should i mark them all as `intent(in)`? But by specifying `intent(in)` what performance gain will I get? I'm compiling for highest optimization with `-O3 flag`. Also what does `pure` do?

Comment: pure tells the compiler that the function has no side effects, and yes, marking all the arguments intent(in) indicates none will change during the function.  And note that -O3 doesn't turn on *all* optimizations; check your compiler manual pages to see if there are any additional optimization flags that could be relevant to this case.

Comment: I googled for `pure` and got the same explanation. `pure function has no side effects`. But what does `side effects` mean here. Apart from `-O3` I'm using `-ipo` as this function is in a different source file.

Comment: @arunmoezhi - "No side effects" for a function means that the function makes no changes to the state of the program other than via its result - it doesn't modify its arguments, it doesn't do IO, doesn't change module variables or variables in common.  PURE procedures have many specific restrictions (all of which are **constraints**) on them that together mean they cannot have side effects.  Note though, that it is not sufficient for a procedure to "practically" have no side effects in order for it to be nominated as pure - it *must* meet all of the specific restrictions.

Comment: Anecdote: *removing* the `pure` keyword actually sped things up by 2x, in my case with `gfortran`. My guess is that `gfortran` couldn't figure out that it could avoid a needless allocation + copy. >_>

Answer (score 4):

Generally the overhead of a procedure call is low.  If the function has 30 lines of code probably you will gain very little because the actual function will dominant over the function call.   If you want to be sure, measure the runtime of the current implementation, then inline the code and measure that runtime.

Comment: I can not totally aggree. Yesterday I struggled with gfortran, that did not inline a 6 line elemental function from the same midule into a triple loop. The cost was enormous. I ended up with a statement function. Of course I used O5, finline-functoons and flto.

Comment: @VladimirF: What could be a reason for not inlining a 6 line function?
Even I had such problems. I have a 30 line function in a different source file and used `-finline-limit=500` along with `-O3` flag but still it was not inlined. But when I used `-ipo` it got inlined and I got 1.5X performance improvement.

Comment: @arunmoezhi, inlining is by default limited to subroutines in the same translation unit. `-ipo` tells the compiler to also look at possible cross-unit optimisations but significantly slows down the compilation and/or could break the code and is thus turned off by default.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Thanks again for coming to my rescue :)
Need some clarifications on your suggestion. What do you mean by same translation unit? And what do you mean by `it could break the code`?

Comment: @arunmoezhi, _same translation unit_ usually means _same source file_ as compilers in general parse one source file at a time. Breaking the code could be observed in some cases with numerically unstable algorithms. Besides I've had some cases where `-ipo` with Intel's compiler resulted in misterious link errors...

Comment: @HristoIliev: This is a double precision code. So will I have problems with using `-ipo`.

Comment: @arunmoezhi, can't say in advance. Just try it and see what happens.